# How to list Accounts in ethers.js 6.0^. it does not have the function listAccounts() like in version below 6.0

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, typescript

```
    async () => {
        console.log("REVALIDATING!!!");
        const accounts = (await provider!._detectNetwork()).toJSON();
        if(!accounts){
            throw "Cannot retreive account! Please, connect to web3 wallet."
        }
        return accounts;
    }
)
return swrRes; }
```

using _detectNetwork() or getNetwork() does not return the current or the list of addresses

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using version 5.4 instead. The reason that you don't have some of the functionalities is because of the beta v6 version. There was a lot of topics recently, talking about problems with the new version. It might be better to use the older stable versions until they roll a stable v6 release.

Comment: yeah that seems to be the viable option, thanks